# Setting up a TeamCity VCS Root to pull using a Mercurial tag

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I am trying to setup a TeamCity build configuration to pull from a Mercurial repository using a Mercurial tag. I have the "Default branch" field of the VCS root set to 'tag name'. Initially I had the "Default branch" field of the VCS root set to 'default' which worked fine but pulls only the tip revision. Here is the TeamCity error that I get:

```
Failed for the root 'mercurial: http://MyRepository/' #46: Cannot find revision 
of the default branch 'tag name' of vcs root mercurial: http://MyRepository
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: I wonder what is your workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, TeamCity doesn't support mercurial tags, only branches and bookmarks are supported. Please vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23468.